# Running a pre-processing tool on source files in makefile before build

Tags: shell, build, makefile, gnu-make

I have a tool lets say `mytool` that does some pre-processing on the source files. Basically, it instruments some functions (based on an input list file) in the source files.

The way it is invoked is : (lets say we have two source files - `input1.c` and `input2.c`)

```
./mytool input1.c input2.c --
```

('--' is for leaving some arguments to default)

Now, I wish to hook this tool to any build process i.e. makefile such that the tool can get all the source files from the makefile and can run on all the source files. So it say there were 3 C files - 1.c, 2.c and 3.c then we would want to do

```
./mytool 1.c 2.c 3.c --
```

and then proceed with the usual build process i.e. 'make' in the simplest case.

How can I achieve this? Is this possible by some sort of variable over-riding?

Comment: Does this tool need to be run on every file all at once like that? Or can it be run on each file individually?

Comment: You want to perform that operation even if Make will then do nothing (e.g. if no files are out of date)?

Comment: @EtanReisner, I would like it to run on every file all at once. However, even if I am able to run it individually, it should be all right for me.

Comment: @Beta Well, that's more of a corner case for me. Even if there is nothing to do for make, I can do 'make clean' and then proceed with usual make after doing the pre-processing step with my tool.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest thing to do, assuming you don't mind the tool running once per `.c` file (as opposed to once for all `.c` files) would be to replace the default `%: %.c` and `%.o: %.c` built-in make rules (assuming those are in use) and add your tool to the body of those rules.

This only runs the tool for files that need to be re-built from source (as per @Beta's comment on the OP).